# How to flip a face of a model to fix a broken mesh in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When exported from Rhino to Unity many FBX models where broken.I tried many things in Rhino created a copy and flipped but the size of the FBX also increased in a big way.Similarly in unity I tried to  get the face which was broken and tried to flip using transform scale x to -1 but it went out of position and getting the face back to its position was really tough.I tried scripting, when I ran unity the mesh(face)flipped but was not showing similar colours a bit darker.So if there are many broken faces and I added this script to every broken faces and flipped will it make the application slower?Any better solution to flip?

```
using System.Linq;

public class Flip : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{

     Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    mesh.triangles = mesh.triangles.Reverse().ToArray();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

[image: Before flipping]
[image: After Flipping]

Comment: this looks like an export problem, I do not know rhino but in max / c4d its often good to bake the geometry inside the package before the export, rather than leave all the modifiers

Comment: @zambari These are final models ,any way in which we can fix this ?

Comment: I recommend to import the model back to the modeling software and fix it there. Not that difficult in fact and better then fixing the mesh at runtime.

Comment: @Dave The problem is that, the models are done in Rhino, when the designers open the models in Rhino they show no problem...But when opened in unity showing problem...I have posted in unity forum but no luck...here is the link https://forum.unity.com/threads/rhino3d-to-unity-3d-export-error.629839/

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in another editor (blender, 3dsmax)? I don't know much about Rhino but if you can export it to one of the standard 3d formats you should be able to do that.

Comment: Also you can try different import settings in the Unity but I don't think it will help.

Comment: @Dave..yeah the models are broken in that too....I checked it in maya and blender...In Maya there is an  option  to export FBX into unity , similarly needed something like Rhino to unity to export

Comment: So what is stopping you from fixing the models in Blender?

Comment: @Dave ..I dont know how to fix broken faces..not a modeller...I dont understand that the model in rhino looks perfect but when taking it as FBX ..model faces disappear